# Trying to get all nodes with at least 2 incoming connections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is the output of the following query:

```
match (u)-[]-(g:Group{group_id : 812794}) return g, u
```

which is presented to show that there indeed exists a group with at least two incoming `[:MEMBER_OF]` connections.

[image]

Now, what I actually want, as described in the title, is to find all groups, and their associated users, with at least two incoming `[:MEMBER_OF]` connections.  I tried the following, which seems to get me all groups with at least two incoming `[:MEMBER_OF]` connections

```
match ()-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group) with  g, count(*) as rel 
where rel > 1 return g
```

but whenever I attempt to get the associated user nodes, it returns nothing.  As in:

```
match (u)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group) with  g, u, count(*) as rel 
where rel > 1 return g, u
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
WITH g, COUNT(u) AS group_size, COLLECT(u) AS users
WHERE group_size > 1
RETURN g, users
```

Comment: While there might be nothing wrong with this answer, code-only answers should strive for an explanation to help future visitors and the original poster of the question.

Comment: @Rapptz Apologies, wrote it from my phone. I'll edit when I get to a computer. :)

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't realize that I needed to use `collect`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This will work for you

```
   match (u)-[r:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group) 
   where count(r) > 1
   return g
```

Comment: @SteveP. I think now this will work. It will return all nodes with at least 2 incoming nodes

Comment: Still doesn't work (this is not a syntactically correct statement), but Nicole's does, so I'm good.